# Prove $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^r \frac{x^n}{n!}}{\sum_{n=1}^r \frac{y^n}{n!}} > \frac{x^s}{y^s}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

> Prove the following inequality:
>   $$\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^r\frac{x^n}{n!}}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^r\frac{y^n}{n!}}>\frac{x^s}{y^s}$$
>   where $r>s$ and $x>y>0$.

### My approach

I tried AM-GM inequality and ended up with $\text{LHS} \ge \left(\dfrac xy\right)^{(r+1)/2}$, then I am stuck.

Comment: Which variable is going from 1 to r?

Comment: r is going from 1 to r. My apologies.forgot to add that.

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: How can r go from 1 to r?

Comment: Ok let me edit the question a bit.Please see the question above.Thnk you.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @KrishanuDasgupta Can you stop changing the variables and figure out what they really are?

Comment: This all looks rather unlikely, Are you sure you have the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes the problem is correctly copied....@lordsharktheunknown

Comment: This inequality cannot be true. Letting $r = 3$, $s = 2$, $x = \sqrt{6}$ and $y = 1$ already violates the condition.